# Extracting only some keys from a JSON file in Bash

Tags: linux, bash

So, I have a JSON file that looks like this ;

```
 {
    "data": { stuff that i need }
    "stuff not needed": {more stuff not needed}
    "data": {more stuff that i need}
 }
```

In short, the stuff that I need is inside the curly braces of the "data" key. How can I print this in a Linux shell command? Note, there are several "data" objects in my file, and I would like to extract data from all of them each one at a time.

The intended output
 would be like this

```
data {...}
data {...}
```

Comment: What did you tried? Did you took a look at `jq`?

Comment: Like @Poshi said, use `jq`. This video has a great explaination about how to use `jq` : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EvpwhGeiH0U

Answer (score 1):

as others suggested you should really use `jq` tool for parsing json format. However if you don't have access to the tool and/or can't install it, below's a very simple way treating the json as raw text (not recommended) and producing the output you want :

```
 grep "\"data\":" json_file | tr -d \"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can very simply use `awk` with the field-separator of `"{"` and the `substr` and `length($2) - 1` to trim the closing `"}"`.

For example with your data:

```
$ awk -F"{" '/^[ ]*"data"/{print substr($2, 1, length($2)-1)}' json
 stuff that i need
more stuff that i need
```

(**note:** you can trim the leading space before `"stuff"` in the 1st line if needed)

**Quick Explanation**

- `awk -F"{"` invoke `awk` with a *field-separator* of `'{'`,
- `/^[ ]*"data"/` locate only lines beginning with zero-or-more spaces followed by `"data"`,
- `print substr($2, 1, length($2)-1)` print the substring of the 2nd field from the first character to the `length-1` character removing the closing `'}'`.

**bash Solution**

With bash you can loop over each line looking for a line beginning with `"data"` and then use a couple of simple *parameter expansions* to remove the unwanted parts of the line from each end. For instance:

```
$ while read -r line; do 
    [[ $line =~ ^\ *\"data\" ]] && { 
        line="${line#*\{}"
        line="${line%\}*}"
        echo $line 
    }
done <json
```

(With your data in the `json` filename, you can just copy/paste into a terminal)

**Example Use/Output**

```
 $ while read -r line; do
>     [[ $line =~ ^\ *\"data\" ]] && {
>         line="${line#*\{}"
>         line="${line%\}*}"
>         echo $line
>     }
> done <json
stuff that i need
more stuff that i need
```

(**note:** bash default word splitting even handles the leading whitespace for you)

While you can do it with `awk` and `bash`, any serious JSON manipulation should be done with the `jq` utility.

Answer (score 1):

With the given input, you can use

```
sed -rn 's/.*"(data)": (.*)/\1 \2/p' inputfile
```